# C - linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have 3 files - String (for getting chars and assembling them into a string (as a pointer, but not array)), the LinkedList file and main (test file). The String part works fine, it's tested. But I got stuck on the LinkedList.

----> I know the problem is in the addString() method and it's a problem in the logic, because I put a print-check at the end of it and I never get there. But I don't seem to find any logical problem... Here's the code for the LinkedList:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"

struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
    struct string *str;
};

static struct node *head;
static struct node *tail;

int count = 0;

void initList()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

void addString(struct string *str_)
{
    struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (head = NULL)
    {
        head = current;
        tail = current;
        current->next = tail;
        current->previous = head;
        current->str = str_;
    }
    else
    {
        current->previous = tail;
        tail->next = current;
        tail = current;
        current->str = str_;
    }

    puts("\nA string has been added!");

}

void deleteString(int index)
{
    struct node *currentNode;
    currentNode = head;
    int i = 0;

    if(index == 0)
    {
        head->str = NULL;
        head->next = head;
        // delete first node and relocate "head" to next node
    }
    while(currentNode != NULL)
    {
        if(i == index)
        {
            currentNode->str = NULL;
            currentNode->previous->next = currentNode->next;
            currentNode->next->previous = currentNode->previous;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
            i++;
        }
        // 1.loop through and starting from 0 as first (head) element
        // 2.when index is reached - delete it and replace the connections
    }
}

void printAll()
{
    struct node *currentNode;
    currentNode = head; 

    while(currentNode !=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", currentNode->str);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }// need to iterate through list
}
```

and here is the test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "String.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    initList();

    char* c;
    c = getChars();

    struct string *strp1;
    strp1 = malloc(sizeof(struct string));
    strp1 = make_string(c);
    addString(strp1);
    printAll();

    printf("%s", *strp1);
    puts("\nsome text");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please make your title describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As eduffy mentioned in your `addString` function you should do a comparison instead of an assignment. The other problem is setting `currentNode->next` and `currentNode->previous`. In your `printAll()` function you iterate until `currentNode == NULL`, which given that `currentNode->next = current node` you will have an infinite loop. Leave `currentNode->next/previous` as `NULL` until you have more than 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

`(head = NULL)` is an assignment statement, not a comparison.  Change it to `(head == NULL)`.

BTW, since it looks like you're just starting out with C, turn up the warning in your compiler flags.  Don't run your code until you've fixed all the warnings.

Comment: And ask how to turn on warnings with your compiler if you can't find out how from manual/with google. For gcc, use switches: -Wall -Wextra